# Why Jquery Validation not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, regex

I'm trying to validate my form before submitting. But, I don't get why below jQuery validations are not working!
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yZXqU/).

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtName" placeholder="Enter Name" />
<input id="txtEmail"  placeholder="Enter Email" /></td>
<input id="txtPhone"  placeholder="Enter Phone" /></td>
<input id="txtWebsite" placeholder="Enter Website" /></td>
<textarea id="txtContent"  placeholder="Your text here.."></textarea>
<button id="btnSend">SEND</button>
```

I'm trying to validate empty input fields and regex validation for email and URL.
**Jquery**

```
    var txtName = $("#txtName");
    var txtEmail = $("#txtEmail");
    var txtPhone = $("#txtPhone");
    var txtWebsite = $("#txtWebsite");
    var txtContent = $("#txtContetnt");

    var emailFilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    var urlFilter = /((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/;
    var phoneFilter = /^\d+$/;

$("#btnSend").click(function (evt) {
    if (txtName.val() == "") {
        txtName.animate({ backgroundColor: '#630000' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (txtEmail.val() == "") {
        txtEmail.animate({ backgroundColor: '#630000' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (txtContent.val() == "") {
        txtEmail.animate({ backgroundColor: '#630000' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!phoneFilter.test(txtPhone.val())) {
        txtEmail.animate({ backgroundColor: '#630000' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!urlFilter.test(txtWebsite.val())) {
        txtContent.animate({ backgroundColor: '#630000' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!emailFilter.test(txtEmail.val())) {
        txtEmail.animate({ backgroundColor: '#630000' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Comment: You're referring to variables like `txtName` in your function, but I don't see where you've initialised them.

Comment: You should remove the repeated lines of code, put them in a function or combine your `if` conditions, but don't repeat the same two lines of code *six* times...

Comment: Also your email regex is totally broken. Consider `/.+@.+\..+/`.

Comment: @meagar can you give an example?

Comment: @MikeW question is now edited..

Comment: Of a valid email your regex rejects? joe+bob@asdf.com

Comment: @MikeW okay let the email one, but what about rest?

Comment: are you have any errors in console?

Answer (score 1):

Your validations appear to be working (except, perhaps, for the email one). However, your jQuery animation is not. This from the jQuery page on `.animate()`:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

Answer (score 0):

When your `Reg exp` get fixed, you need to compare each element's value to match with `Reg exp` value..

You can do this by either of this method,

```
function IsEmailAddressValid(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

then you can check for valid email address like

```
if(!IsEmailAddressValid(emailaddress)) 
{ 
  /* do something, it will give true if email is valid */ 
}
```

you can create functions for matching your separate `Reg exp` for re usability.

or you can `match` your selector value with `Reg exp` as i did in this [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZXqU/21/)

i was in kind of hurry so i try to cover up as much as possible. I have edited some of your exisiting code.

**FYI:** Regular expression may or may not give desired results. Search for one that fits your need and its all good. hope that helps.

**EDIT:** As @Mike W has mentioned, your .animate() was not working on fiddle so i replaced it with my error class.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery validation seems have some little mistakes:

I've updated your jQuery as below:([Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yZXqU/25/))

```
//Validation

var txtName = $("#txtName");
var txtEmail = $("#txtEmail");
var txtPhone = $("#txtPhone");
var txtWebsite = $("#txtWebsite");
var txtContent = $("#txtContent");

var emailFilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
var urlFilter = /((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/;
var phoneFilter = /^\d+$/;

$("#btnSend").click(function (evt) {
    if (txtName.val() == "") {
        txtName.css('background-color', '#630000');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (txtEmail.val() == "") {

        txtEmail.css('background-color', '#630000');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }


    if (txtContent.val() == "") {

        txtContent.css('background-color', '#630000');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!phoneFilter.test(txtPhone.val())) {

        txtPhone.css('background-color', '#630000');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!urlFilter.test(txtWebsite.val())) {

        txtWebsite.css('background-color', '#630000');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!emailFilter.test(txtEmail.val())) {

        txtEmail.css( 'background-color', '#630000');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }


});
txtName.click(function() {
    txtName.removeAttr("style");
});
txtEmail.click(function() {
    txtEmail.removeAttr("style");
});
txtPhone.click(function() {
    txtPhone.removeAttr("style");
});
txtWebsite.click(function() {
    txtWebsite.removeAttr("style");
});
txtContent.click(function() {
    txtContent.removeAttr("style");
});
txtName.focus(function() {
    txtName.removeAttr("style");
});
txtEmail.focus(function() {
    txtEmail.removeAttr("style");
});
txtContent.focus(function() {
    txtContent.removeAttr("style");
});
```